# Why this expression does not unbound the variable?

Tags: erlang

Recently I started learning Erlang, coming from an imperative background things are somewhat different...

I was doing fine (learning Erlang) till I came across something I did not understood while working in Eshell, can someone explain me what is happening?

```
17> One.
1
18> One = 1.
1
19> true andalso f(One).
ok
20> One.
1
```

Why `One` is still bound to a value? Since the right side of the expression was indeed evaluated. Now, If I use `f()` alone, things work as expected

```
21> f(One).
ok
22> One.
* 1: variable 'One' is unbound
```

Why?

Comment: look this: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81160

Comment: @Atomic_alarm what exactly? ...  that's actually my point, the second expression was evaluated, I know it because it returned `ok`, but the variable was not unbound. am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are no current variable bindings, the command

```
1> One = 1.
```

adds a binding for `One` by calling `erl_eval:add_binding('One',1,[])` where the final argument is a list of current bindings. The bindings are then `[{'One',1}]`.

Next, we run the `andalso` expression:

```
2> true andalso f(One).
ok
3> b().
One = 1
ok
```

What happens for this command is that when `true` gets evaluated, the bindings are `[{One,1}]`. Since `true` makes the left-hand side of the `andalso` successful, the right-hand side is then evaluated, also with bindings of `[{One,1}]`, and the `f(One)` command there results in a call to `erl_eval:del_binding('One',[{'One',1}])`, changing the bindings *for only the right-hand side* to the empty list `[]`. The result of that part of the expression, `ok`, becomes the overall result because of the way `andalso` works. Once that result is available, the bindings for the right-hand side are dropped because all that's needed is the result. The original bindings are still around because of the left-hand side, and those bindings stay in effect. The subsequent `b()` command to show the bindings therefore still shows `One = 1`.

A very similar effect happens if you run this:

```
4> true andalso (Two = 2).
2
5> b().
One = 1
ok
```

The second part of the `andalso`, `(Two = 2)`, adds a binding for `Two` only to the bindings for that part of the evaluation. The result, `2`, is kept, but the bindings for that part are dropped, and only the bindings for the left half stay in effect. When we again run `b()` to see all bindings, we still see only `One = 1`.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you very much. But, what's happening? I mean, you said `The original bindings are still around because of the left-hand side` what does that means? you mean, Erlang creates another scope just for Boolean expressions? also, does this logic applies outside of the shell?

Comment: First, this occurs only in the shell, since `f` is a shell-specific function, and if you try to compile my second example (containing `Two=2`) the compiler fails with the error `variable 'Two' unsafe in 'andalso'`, which means that not all branches of the expression set `Two`. Erlang doesn't create a new scope for boolean expressions; rather, when the shell evaluates expressions it carries variable bindings for those expressions, and in this case the bindings for the right side of `andalso` are dropped after it's evaluated while the ones for the left side are kept. I think it's a shell bug.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in `erl_eval` as well. [Its code for handling andalso](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/erl_eval.erl#L448-L457) shows how the bindings for evaluating the second part of `andalso` are dropped (line 452) and only those for the first part are kept. If the bindings for part 2 are instead kept and are merged with `Bs1` on line 457, then my `true andalso (Two=2)` example results in an added binding in the shell for `Two`, but it still doesn't fix the original case involving `f(One)`. I think the shell would need some additional special handling for that.

Comment: Then again maybe it's not a bug at all, given how the compiler correctly refuses to compile such a construct due to the unsafe variable problem I mentioned in an earlier comment.

Comment: @Steve: if you try `ok == f(One).` in the shell, the expression is evaluated in a separated scope, returns true, but does not affect the shell scope (meaning that One is still in the binding list). same thing if you put it in the left side of the andalso. I don't think it is a bug: it was necessary to make  a choice since this feature is only available in the shell, and it seems that different shell cases are consistent.

Comment: @Pascal: I've also concluded it's not a bug. But try `(Three=3) + `(Four=4)` which in shell results in new bindings for both variables. This is due to the way `erl_eval` handles different operators; for the `+` operator and others it merges the bindings from the two sides after performing the operation. It's easy to change `andalso` and `orelse` to do that too, but like I said earlier, it still won't change what happens with the `f(One)` cases. Also, note that your `ok == f(One)` is different than `andalso` because like `+` it merges the bindings from both sides of the `==`.

Comment: Thank you, for now I will stay away from those type of expressions, at least till I feel more comfortable with the language. Fortunately now I know what's really happening